# python Name error: class"BankAccount" is not defined

Tags: python

I have a python code and I receive following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/SUVI/Desktop/SUVIwork/BankAccount.py", line 1, in <module>
class BankAccount:
File "C:/Users/SUVI/Desktop/SUVIwork/BankAccount.py", line 26, in     BankAccount
myAccount =BankAccount(00000, "XXXXXX")
NameError: name 'BankAccount' is not defined
```

**Code:**

```
class BankAccount: // Here I defined the class" BankAccount"
def __init__(self, acct_number, acct_name):
    self.acct_number = acct_number
    self.acct_name =acct_name
    self.balance = 0.0

def  displayBalance(self):
    print " The account balance is:", self.balance

def deposit(self, amount):
    self.banlance = self.balance + amount
    print "You deposited", amount
    print " The new balance is :", self.balance

def withdraw(self, amount):
    if self.balance >= amount:
        self.balance = self.balance - amount
        print "You withdrew", amount
        print " The new balance is:", self.balance

    else:
        print "You tried to withdraw", amount
        print " The account balance is:", self.balance
        print " Withdrawal denied. No enough funds."

myAccount =BankAccount(00000, "XXXXXX")
print "Account name :", myAccount.acct_name
print "Account number:", myAccount.acct_number
myAccount.displayBalance()

myAccount.deposit(100)
nyAccount.withdraw(57.55)
myAccount.withdraw(67.18)
```

I already defined the class before creating an instance of the class.
Why it can not find my class? I really appreciate your input!

Comment: I used the python2.7 under Windows 8,tks!

Comment: Did you copy and paste the indentation correctly? It doesn't look right.

Comment: You also have a typo here: `self.banlance = self.balance + amount`

Comment: Please change nyAccount.withdraw(57.55) to MyAccount.withdraw(57.55)..
 It is not giving any error.

Comment: As per the traceback ``myAccount =BankAccount(00000, "XXXXXX")`` is a part of ``class BankAccount`` definition and hence gives the error. You should indent your program properly

Comment: Thanks so much every one, It is solved, Thanks !

Comment: I updated my answer for further improvements and a little help at the end.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code

**First** of all, your indentation is off, please see this [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) to learn the correct indentation.

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, acct_number, acct_name):
        self.acct_number = acct_number
        self.acct_name =acct_name
        self.balance = 0.0

    def  displayBalance(self):
        print " The account balance is:", self.balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance = self.balance + amount
        print "You deposited", amount
        print " The new balance is :", self.balance

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.balance >= amount:
            self.balance = self.balance - amount
            print "You withdrew", amount
            print " The new balance is:", self.balance

        else:
            print "You tried to withdraw", amount
            print " The account balance is:", self.balance
            print " Withdrawal denied. No enough funds."
```

**Second:**
You have a typo in **deposit**

```
self.banlance = self.balance + amount
```

should be

```
self.balance = self.balance + amount
```

**Third**
you have a typo at

```
nyAccount.withdraw(57.55)
```

should be

```
myAccount.withdraw(57.55)
```

**Fourth**
You are not using the right funtion-name-style.

`displayBalance` should be named `display_balance`

Please see the official naming conventions in this [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

**A little recommendation:**
It seems like you are writing your code in an editor.
Maybe you should look into some IDEs like pycharm community edition.
Those help you with happy little accidents like typos and indentation.